# cairo graphics inside my_conky.lua is eating memory when I use surface_create_from_png

Tags: memory, graphics, conky, lua, cairo

I tried adding images to my `conky.lua` with the following function

```
function drawimage(cr,img)
    image = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png (img)
    cairo_set_source_surface (cr, image, screen.x, screen.y)
    cairo_paint (cr)
    cairo_surface_destroy (image)
end
```

After starting `conky` my pc took a few minutes to get frozen. After a reboot, I realized that `cairo_image_surface_create_from_png()` function that eats my ram memory.

How can I prevent that, if possible?

Comment: presumably there's not a memory leak in the function and it needs the memory to do the work you've asked it to do? It's not clear to me what the appropriate response would be here.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the memory isn't released until conky closes or when the configuration is reloaded.

Instead of creating the surface on each call to `drawimage`, you could make a function x that creates the surface and a function y that destroys the surface, call x from `lua_startup_hook`, and call y from `lua_shutdown_hook`.  That way, the surface would only be created once at Conky startup or config reload and destroyed once at Conky shutdown or config reload.

See man conky for details on `lua_startup_hook` and `lua_shutdown_hook`.